# I've set a background on my html, now how do I set the background of one id to be a different color?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSSand I have been trying to figure out what I've been doing wrong all night.

I would like to set the background color of `div` with id="transparentBox" to be a different color (eventually a and off-white box with some currently unknown opacity setting) However, it seems as thought the styling I'm applying via CSS isn't doing the trick. Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

I've set a background on my HTML, now how do I set the background of one id to be a different color?

```css
    html
    {
     text-align: center;
     background: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 0%, #0066ff 100%) fixed;
    }

    body
    {
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    p
    {
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    .off
    {
     color: #F0FFFF;
    }
    
    #header
    {
     height:100px;
     width:960px;
    }
    
    #header h1
    {
     position: relative;
     text-align: left;
     color: #000000;
     font-size: 45px;
     left: 5px;
     top: 20px;
    }
    
    body 
    {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     text-align: left;
     font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    #navigationBar
    {
     height: 40px;
     background-color: #F0FFFF;
     border-color: #000000;
    }
    
    ul 
    {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #333;
    }
    
    li 
    {
     float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 13px;
     padding-bottom: 13px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     padding-right: 15px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
    li a:hover 
    {
     background-color: #111;
    }
    
    .active 
    {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
    
    #navigationMenu
    {
     margin-top: 0px;
     height: auto;
     background-color: #F0FFFF;
     border-color: #000000;
     border-radius: 25px;
    }
    
    #transparentBox
    {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 500px;
     height: 400px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     border-color: #000000;
     border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.calebwolff.us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    
        <title>Caleb Wolff's Personal Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Caleb<span class="off">Wolff</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="navigationBar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.calebwolff.us">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/calebwolffmusic/">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="transparnetBox">
            <h1>HELLLOOO</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id name in css and html are different(typo), in css its '#transparentBox' and in html it is 'transparnetBox'.

Please make sure the id name every where you use are the same. You can always use browser developer tools to check and inspect styling on DOM elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.calebwolff.us">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<title>Caleb Wolff's Personal Website</title>
<style>
    html {
        text-align: center;
        background: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 0%, #0066ff 100%) fixed;
    }

    body {
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .off {
        color: #F0FFFF;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100px;
        width: 960px;
    }

    #header h1 {
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 45px;
        left: 5px;
        top: 20px;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: left;
        font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #navigationBar {
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #F0FFFF;
        border-color: #000000;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 13px;
        padding-bottom: 13px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }

    #navigationMenu {
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #F0FFFF;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }

    #transparnetBox {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #000000;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Caleb<span class="off">Wolff</span></h1>
</div>

<div id="navigationBar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.calebwolff.us">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/calebwolffmusic/">Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="transparnetBox">
<h1>HELLLOOO</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I spent so much time on that. A fresh pair of eyes is always helpful! Much appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

To change the background there are two methods

1. Change color normally without shades as

   `html 
   {
       text-align: center;
       background: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 70%, #0066ff 100%) fixed;
   }`
2. Change color with gradient shades
   you should change the colors in html style with color codes of 6 digits
   `html 
   {
       text-align: center;
       background: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 70%, #0066ff 100%) fixed;
   }`
   There are list of color codes available and opacity of those colors are set in percentage.You can try either of these two methods.

Comment: My apologies, I have successfully changed the background. That is not what I am asking. I am trying to change the background color of one id within the body.

Answer (score 0):

Adding color styling to the `<html>` tag rather than the `<body>` tag is a bit unusual. Why not change that to the `<body>` tag?

On another note, try this:

```
#transparentBox
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Changing the background within the body tag could cause the page to display with white at the bottom of the page if the body doesn't take up the entire screen. I was running into this issue on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Check the typo between `<div id="transparnetBox">` and `# transparentBox`.
You had to check your block in the browser and see that you do not have any styles for this component, and not just "background colors."

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand the typo part but could you explain the second part of your answer?

Comment: @CalebWolff, the first thing I did was open your code in the browser, inspect broken component and see there is no styles at all. So, the most obvious variant is a typo.

Comment: I see, I'll have to work on understanding the basic debugging tricks of front-end development. Thank you!